# Error starting Wildfly 10.0.0.final on server with Domain Config

Tags: java, windows, wildfly-10

Good Day,

I am trying to learn how to use java with wildfly.
I am able to start wildfly with no problems on my Win 10 machine in standalone mode. I was able to work through the tutorials with no problems.
I have now tried to use my server environment but I cant seem to start wildfly with the domain config.

I initially had an error with -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m and found out that I needed to update my JAVA.
I have been scouring the internet for any help on the configuration, message, warnings and errors that wildfly gives but cant seem to find a similar problem. Also looked at each console and port configuration issue that I could find discussed but nothing I change seems to affect it.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have wildfly-10.0.0.Final available with PATH variable set. 
I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 x64bit VM Server.
I have jdk1.8.0_91. 
I am getting the problem while trying to start server with domain.bat

The result is:

```
Calling "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\winterpol\wildfly\bin\domain.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8_92\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\winterpol\wildfly"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8_92\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms64M -Xmx512M  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -server"

===============================================================================

14:00:30,991 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
14:00:31,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (main) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Host Controller'
[Host Controller] 14:00:31,743 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
[Host Controller] 14:00:31,930 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
[Host Controller] 14:00:31,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Servlet 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
[Host Controller] 14:00:32,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0003: Creating http management service using network interface (management) port (9990) securePort (-1)
[Host Controller] 14:00:32,679 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.3.4.Final
[Host Controller] 14:00:32,679 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.4.Final
[Host Controller] 14:00:32,757 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final
[Host Controller] 14:00:32,788 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYRMT0001: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999

[Host Controller] 14:00:32,788 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.http.api.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDMHTTP0003: Unable to load console module for slot main, disabling console
[Host Controller] 14:00:33,100 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0369: Required capabilities are not available:
[Host Controller]     org.wildfly.domain.server-group.other-server-group in context 'server-config'; There are no known registration points which can provide this capability.
[Host Controller] 14:00:33,100 FATAL [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0034: Host Controller boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
[Host Controller] 14:00:33,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Servlet 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) stopped in 11ms
14:00:33,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (reaper for Host Controller) WFLYPC0011: Process 'Host Controller' finished with an exit status of 99
14:00:33,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process] (Thread-8) WFLYPC0017: Shutting down process controller
14:00:33,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process] (Thread-8) WFLYPC0016: All processes finished; exiting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue with the WildFly Servlet distribution. There is a workaround on the [JIRA (WFLY-6201)](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6201). Basically the `other-server-group` profile is missing and needs to be added.